# What changes to my HTML and JavaScript code do I need to make, in order for my character_count to work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am currently working on a WordPress website, with WooCommerce functionality.

One of my tasks is to insert a Custom Text Field on the Product Page, where shoppers are able to assign a piece of text they would like to see on their Product.  To speed up the process, I have used a Plugin.  To generate this Custom Field, the Plugin Outputs the following code on the Product Page:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fields-group-1">    

    <table class="fields_table  product-custom-text-wrapper" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="label"><label class=" product-custom-text-label" for="custom_text">Custom Text</label></td>
                <td class="value">
                    <input type="text" class="field product-custom-text" name="custom_text" value="" placeholder="Enter Custom Text ..." maxlength="16" type="text" pattern="mandatory" mandatory="no"  />
                    <span class="validation-message is-valid-1"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

I would now like to Output the Character Count to the Product Page.  After browsing the net, I can see the following code would help with this:

**JavaScript**

```
$('textarea').keyup(updateCount);
$('textarea').keydown(updateCount);

function updateCount() {
    var cs = $(this).val().length;
    $('#character_count').text(cs);
}
```

At present, the code does not work.  Using the HTML above, is anyone aware what I would need to change the 'textarea' in the JavaScript code to, in order for this code to work?

Once I have got the code working, I can then simply enter `<span id="character_count"></span>` for the code to be complete.

Comment: "input .product-custom-text"

Comment: Your HTML does not contain `textarea` or `#character_count`?

Comment: Thanks @Jonas w . @AP ... As I was using a Plugin, it did not generate the `textarea` tag.  As for the `character_count` ID, this is within the <span> tags, which I would be inserted once I had fixed the above code.  Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery selector `$('textarea')` is incorrect as there is no textarea in your HTML. It looks like you want to use `$('.product-custom-text')` instead. Of course it would be better to select it using an ID rather than a class by adding an ID to your input tag.

The selectors for jQuery are the same for CSS. So if you want to exactly select an element, use it's ID.

Your code becomes:

```
$('.product-custom-text').keyup(updateCount);
$('.product-custom-text').keydown(updateCount);

function updateCount() {
    var cs = $(this).val().length;
    $('#character_count').text(cs);
}
```

EDIT:

To include a character count only in products which have the text box, I would include it in the same scope of the table and use CSS to position it correctly.

For example:

```js
$('.product-custom-text').keyup(updateCount);
$('.product-custom-text').keydown(updateCount);

function updateCount() {
    var cs = $(this).val().length;
   $(this).next().next().text(cs);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fields-group-1">    

    <table class="fields_table  product-custom-text-wrapper" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="label"><label class=" product-custom-text-label" for="custom_text">Custom Text</label></td>
                <td class="value">
                    <input type="text" class="field product-custom-text" name="custom_text" value="" placeholder="Enter Custom Text ..." maxlength="16" type="text" pattern="mandatory" mandatory="no"  />
                    <span class="validation-message is-valid-1"></span>
                    <span id="character_count"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td class="label"><label class=" product-custom-text-label" for="custom_text">Custom Text</label></td>
                <td class="value">
                    <input type="text" class="field product-custom-text" name="custom_text" value="" placeholder="Enter Custom Text ..." maxlength="16" type="text" pattern="mandatory" mandatory="no"  />
                    <span class="validation-message is-valid-1"></span>
                    <span id="character_count"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

This update contradicts my former part about wanting to select with an ID, in this case we ant to select by class as there are multiple products on the same page.

Take note of the `.next().next()` portion of the code. This skips the validation message span and grabs the span for the character count. This can be optimized but works for now. You can try it live in the example window.

Comment: Thank you Donny.  Do you, by any chance, know how to modify said code, so that it only appears within certain Product Categories/Products?  I'll be outputting the Character_Count, using the following: `<span id="character_count"></span>` .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you mean you want to add a unique character count to individual products on a page with multiple products?

Comment: Sorry, yes.  The Custom Text Field only appears on some Products.  These Products are all within the same 'Custom Products' Category.  Consequently, I would only like the Character_Count to appear on such Products/Product Categories.  Is there anyway to achieve this?  Thanks for your time with this.

Comment: Are you saying that by modifying the code, so that it shows `$(this).next().next().text(cs);`, that the Character Count will only be Outputted on pages where the Custom Field appears?

Comment: I'm not sure how it is rendered as you don't have any source PHP code. However the span will only be modified if the custom field exists

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any `<textarea>`s on the page. Add an `id="whatever"` attribute to the `<input />` element, and change the `$('textarea')` selectors to `$('#whatever')`.

Comment: Please show relevant updates to the code to make it complete. And upvote worthy!

Comment: Thanks for your time and useful directive.